# New ReactNative App Triggers Bundler Error: error Unexpected token =

Tags: react-native

Every time I try to create a new React Native app, I receive this error in the Metro Bundler:

```
error Unexpected token =.
/Users/lukeschoenberger/repos/PodApp/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stores/HttpStore.js:31
  static HttpError = HttpError;
                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lukeschoenberger/repos/PodApp/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stores/HttpGetStore.js:12:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

I'm running: `npx react-native run-ios`.

When I create the script, I create the app, I run: `npx react-native init AppName`

I'm on node v14.17.1.

The startup script also says: `success Successfully launched the app on the simulator`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What tutorial are you trying to follow? Are you using Typescript or Javascript? And are you running this on a Mac computer that has Xcode installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error because I was running on node v10.

After switching to node v14.17.5 (npm v6.14.14) via nvm, it solved the issue.
Can you verify you are really on v14.17.1?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried using node v14.17.5 and it didn't work. I removed:

```
static HttpError = HttpError;
static NetworkError = NetworkError;
```

from `node_modules/metro-config/node_modules/metro-cache/src/stores/HttpStore.js`
and it worked.

Can use patch-package as well:

```
yarn patch-package metro-config/metro-cache
```